# SafeCracker: «You must specify a valid entry to edit.»

Tags: safecracker, error

SafeCracker gives me a Error after submitting an edit-form…

```
{exp:safecracker channel='xy' … entry_id='{segment_3}'}
```

- The URL contains the entry_id @ segment_3
- All field-values are included in their respective custom fields
- If I look into the rendered HTML, the entry_id is all over the place like: `<input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="15771">` and others (RET, URI) … ditto for the correct values for author_id, channel_id, site_id etc. (see below)

If I submit the form, the following error gets displayed.

> You must specify a valid entry to edit.

BUT an interesting fact: the entry gets saved anyway!

*System: EE 2.5.5*

**EDIT:** All the hiddenFields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="21">
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="http://domain.com/dir/dir2/15771">
<input type="hidden" name="URI" value="dir/dir2/15771">
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="dir/dir2/success/15771">
<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="channel_id" value="16">
<input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="15771">
<input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="dir/dir2/success/15771">
<input type="hidden" name="allow_comments" value="y">
```

Comment: What's the return url of the tag? …........................

Comment: I've updated the Question with all the hiddenFields … including return_url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> The URL contains the entry_id @ segment_3

But

The return url has "success" as segment_3.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="dir/dir2/success/15771">
```

This is not a valid entry.

You can either change

```
 {exp:safecracker channel='xy' … entry_id='{segment_3}'}
```

to

```
 {exp:safecracker channel='xy' … entry_id='{segment_4}'}
```

Or change the url return path to something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="dir/dir2/15771/success">
```

Comment: who had thought that entry_id and return do conflict each other … :-) … thx @okenathan!

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the entry id as ENTRY_ID in the return?

```
{exp:safecracker channel="channel_name" return="channel_name/edit/ENTRY_ID" entry_id="{segment_3}"}
```